# Axios request get value from nested array in Vue

Tags: json, vue.js, axios

In a .vue file I am trying the get value from an axios get response result which is in a nested array. The code looks like the example below (without a search form for query).

```
<div class="results" v-if="results">
  <p>{{ results }}</p>
  <p>{{ result }}</p>
</div>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  name: 'search',
  data () {
    return {
      query '',
      results: '',
      result: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getResults(query) {
      axios.get('https://apiexample.com/api/search.php?t_id=' + query).then( response => {
          this.results = response.data.items;
          this.result = response.data.items[0]['1:B'];
      });
    }
  }
}
```

So for this.results I get something similar to

```
[{"1:A":10,"1:B":20,"1:C":30,"1:D":40,"1:E":50},
{"1:A":20,"1:B":30,"1:C":40,"1:D":50,"1:E":60},
{"1:A":30,"1:B":40,"1:C":50,"1:D":60,"1:E":70},
{"1:A":40,"1:B":50,"1:C":60,"1:D":70,"1:E":80}]
```

For this.result I am getting undefined when I am trying to get the value of 20. Probably navigating that type of response incorrectly or perhaps something more specific needs to be added to data() {}?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you check `typeof this.results`? Is it `object` or `string`?

Comment: yeah, maybe JSON.parse is needed here. Otherwise looks fine.

Comment: I'd think about the data structure for a moment. Nobody will understand "1:B" and so on. Besides writing code like this is pain.

Comment: `response.data.items[0]['1:B'];`  should work.   Something else is causing this issue.

Comment: skirtle using typeof reveals it is a string and sandrooco yes I agree however this data structure is used in someone else's api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, `response.data.items` is a string, not an object. This seems like a flawed API response, with the `items` unnecessarily encoded as a JSON string within the response.

However, assuming that fixing the problem in the server is not possible, the `items` can be decoded in the UI:

```js
this.results = JSON.parse(response.data.items);
this.result = this.results[0]['1:B'];
```